# JAX-B class generation from schema compound by multiple files

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I am using JAX-b to generate classes out of an XSD schema (compound by multiple files, and I dont know whether this is the problem) and the result is not what I was expecting.The objects created does not provide getters for single attributes but they offer getter for the list of the attributes as **Object**, and I have to cast each object manually.

i.e.
the file **lom.xsd** has:

```
  <xs:include schemaLocation="common/elementTypes.xsd"/>
  <xs:include schemaLocation="common/rootElement.xsd"/>
```

in the file **elementTypes.xsd** we have:

```
    <xs:complexType name="lom">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
         <xs:group ref="general"/>
         <xs:group ref="lifeCycle"/>
       </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
```

instead in the **rootElement.xsd** we have

```
     <xs:element name="lom" type="lom">
       <xs:unique name="lomUnique">
         <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
         <xs:field xpath="@uniqueElementName"/>
      </xs:unique>
     </xs:element>
```

What I get is the class:

```
 public class General{
      List<Object> titleOrlifeCicle
 }
```

and I would pretend to have:

```
   public class General{
     String title;
     String lifeCicle
   }
```

In other schema it works fine, but it looks like with schema in different files it doesnt help that much. Is there any way to get the second version from the schema?
Thank you.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the relevant bits of your schema.

Comment: well, you can find the schema in : [lom schema](http://ltsc.ieee.org/xsd/lomv1.0/)

Comment: That's not encouraging people to answer. If you want an answer, you have to give people the relevant information in a digestible form.

Comment: You are right but the elements are nested and its not that easy to put the example in three lines. But I will try to find the way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to be sure about is that correctly having the same content in numerous XSDs vs. few, wouldn't change the outcome of your generation process. The problem in your case is that your schema makes heavy use of xsd:choice, hence the naming of your getters. The choice being unbounded, you're getting a list; you could make the names friendlier, using custom bindings, but that won't change the underlying structure. In your case, you would have to navigate The objects in the list, try to see if they match a class "General" or "LifeCycle", which will have the strings you're looking for the attributes you're after (see diagram below).

[image: LOM.xsd]

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I have tried it and it works, but then its not worth to use anymore Jaxb, I can just parse the object with the DOMParser, and I could have a faster solution (espetialy for unmarshalling). Thank you

Comment: @pokeRex110... and you wouldn't be wrong doing it, especially if the data involved in the exchange is not that large. For sure, a pure XML processing model gives you much more flexibility when it comes to versioning, etc.; just make sure you do it in a way that keeps the code maintenable....